# How to delete all entities connected to a entity connected through Key property in appengine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have following data store model.

```
class UserDetail(ndb.Model):
    name=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email=ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    posts=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Post',repeated=True)

class Post(ndb.Model):
    subject=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content=ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    created=ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    user=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='UserDetail')
    comments=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Comment',repeated=True)

class Comment(ndb.Model):
    body=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='UserDetail')
    post=ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Post')
```

Basically what i want to do is to delete a post.And when i delete the post its all comments should get deleted and the post should also get deleted from User's post list from UserDetail model.The way i know to delete is to delete the post and the search the comment model with given post id and delete all of them and same way go to the user's posts list and delete the required post.
Is there any better way to do it.

Comment: Side comment: I'd drop the `posts` property from `UserDetail` and the `comments` property from `Post` - they're a scalability problem: you have to re-write those entities every time you add/delete an element in those lists. And the complicate the logic of creating/deleting an element which now also has to be added to/removed from those lists. You can obtain those lists on-demand by queries (subject to eventual consistency, indeed, but is that really an issue in this usage case?)

Comment: Well the reason I created this model schema is to compensate the fact that I am not using a relational database. I mean if I were to make a profile page for a user and want to display all of the users post this schema will help.I don't know how I will achieve this easily if I do what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to define a `pre_delete_hook`. This is a function that runs before an entity is deleted. Let this function itself delete any Comments that refer to this post. You can also let it remove the key value from `UserDetails` as well. The code will be something like this:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def _pre_delete_hook(cls, key):
        comments = Comment.query(Comment.post==key).fetch(keys_only=True)
        ndb.delete_multi(comments)

        details = UserDetail.query(UserDetail.posts.IN([key])).fetch()
        for detail in details:
            detail.posts.remove(key)
        ndb.put_multi(details)
```

The reason you should user a hook is so you guarantee that the functions you want will be executed no matter what part of the code tried to delete a `Post`. It is a way to compensate the fact that you are not using a relational database.

You can find more details on hooks in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#hooks). I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this would indeed work regardless of the invocation context. For example I doubt it will work if `.delete()` is called inside a transaction - non-ancestor queries are not allowed inside transactions. Also it leaves room for orphan comment leftovers due to eventual consistency. Instead I'd just enqueue a delayed push queue task to perform the deletion of the related entities in a better controlled context.

Comment: Hello. Yes it will. No matter how you delete the instance (whether `.delete()` or `ndb.delete_multi()`) it will work.

I have used it with large-scale data before and it never created an eventual consistency problem with me, especially if you use `pre_put_hook` and not `post_put_hook`.

Comment: Thanks @Y2H. But when i applied this code in my program it gives me an Type Error saying key property object is not iterable. I am unable to figure out why this is saying .I checked it in console and it was working fine there.

Comment: It is not showing any line from my code.These are the last few lines what terminal is showing.  File "/home/asmodeus/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3971, in delete_multi_async
    return [key.delete_async(**ctx_options) for key in keys]
TypeError: 'KeyProperty' object is not iterable

Comment: I believe the error is coming in ndb.delete_multi(comments).

Comment: The code as I wrote it should not produce this error. Try to log `type(comments)` and check if it is in fact a list.

Comment: I don't know why but i looped over comments and deleted them one at a time and it is working flawless.Don't know whats the problem.Great thanks @Y2H

Comment: Happy to help. If you need more help with using `ndb.delete_multi()` feel free to give me the exact code you employed.